# csf.conf file. Allow MySQL Access From External IP Address - not working,

Tags: mysql, firewall, cpanel

I edit my CSF file in vi, but the ConfigServer Security&Firewall will not load in the web-browser after saving, so I have to revert. I assume because of invalid syntax?

I have these ports permitted (CSF works fine and displays in WHM):

```
# Allow incoming TCP ports
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995"


# Allow outgoing TCP ports
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,37,43,53,80,110,113,443,587,873"
```

However, when I also add in this line:

```
tcp|in|d=3306|s=11.22.33.44
```

to the conf file and save, the WHM in the ConfigServer Security&Firewall will not display. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this into the allowed IPs box on WHM will solve the issue. Do not add this directly into the CSF file.

Answer (score 0):

You can white list IPs using the command.

> csf -a IP

after that restarting csf is a good practice.

> csf -r